# MS Access MultiValue query

Tags: ms-access

My charity's Access database has 2 tables for volunteers:

```
Volunteers:
VID - ID of volunteer
ActiveGroups - Multivalue list of VolunteerGroups that they're active in
InterestGroupss - Multuvalue list of VolunteerGroups that they are interested in

VolunteerGroups:
ID - ID of group
GroupName - name of group
```

I need to write a query listing people who are interested in a group, but not part of that group and am completely stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Publish the schema. If you have multiple values in an attribute then you're not in 1NF and you need to fix  that before continuing.

Comment: @nicomp Access multi-valued fields are really separate tables to handle many-to-many relationships for people that do not want to see or use the extra tables. They are 1NF since they are actually separate tables (according to Microsoft at least, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-multivalued-fields-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I see what you mean. Those are super dumb and I don't use them: I just create the foreign key and populate the controls when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Multivalue fields are a hassle and should be avoided, but as far as I know, this should work (it joins the VolunteerGroups table twice, once inner on InterestGroups to check the person is in that group, and once left on ActiveGroupss so you can check the person is not in that group)

```
SELECT VID 
FROM Volunteers 
Inner Join VolunteerGroups As InterestedGroup ON InterestedGroup.ID = InterestedGroupss.Value 
LEFT JOIN VolunteerGroups As ActiveGroup ON ActiveGroup.ID = ActiveGroups.Value
WHERE ActiveGroup.ID Is Null
```